# javascript, button, click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 questions, both regarding clicking via js.

So I am on a site and I wish to automate a physical click on 2 buttons, I learned that if we `getElementbyId.click()` we can do this. But both these buttons do not have an ID. I tried coordinate clicking and it doesn't work and also by the class but to no avail.

```
<td data-pick="red" class="red" rowspan="2"></td>
```

How do I click on this?

and also

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success">GO</button>
```

and this.

`document.getElementsByClassName` doesn't work :(

Comment: What do you mean `document.getElementsByClassName` doesn't work? If you call `document.getElementsByClassName('red')` you'll get a collection which contains the `<td>`.

Comment: have you set up a handler to run when the element is clicked? also, you said these don't have an id. why not?

Comment: @MikeC I think he means it doesn't work if you call `click()` on the `HTMLCollection` which is returned. It has to be iterated over. Even if there's only 1 element.

Comment: Can you specify an `id` or a `name` for the elements?

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to this, so i don't know if you guys would be able to see this, so I'm tagging @MikeC when i use getElementsByClass('red'), i get multiple results, with all corresponding td with class red. But i only want to click the one with data-pick red. There can be td data-pick="1" class "red",td data-pick="2" class "red",td data-pick="3" class "red" but what if i only want to click td data-pick="red" class "red". Thank you so much for the help provided

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to trigger a click using `document.getElementsByClassName` but you have to understand what you get back from `document.getElementsByClassName` is not an individual element, but a list which you can iterate over.

You can trigger a click for every item in a collection by doing the following:

```
var redClassElements = document.getElementsByClassName('red');

for(var i=0;i<redClassElements.length;i++) {
    redClassElements[i].click();
}
```

This will do nothing if you haven't assigned a `click handler` to the element `click()` is being called on though.

Also, do you really want to trigger a click on multiple elements? Your best bet is to assign the element an id as has been suggested to you. You can then use `document.getElementById('theId').click()`.

Comment: Oh My Gosh. Thank you so much! i used this method but i replaced i with the number i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
document.getElementsByClassName('red')[0].click();
```

Why [0] ? because **getElementsByClassName** returns classes (matching DOM elements) in form of an array, so [0] is the index here :-)
And for your second button you can trigger the click using

```
document.querySelector("button[type=submit]").click();
```

By the way if you are using jquery then why don't you use

```
$(".red").click();
$("button[type=submit]").click();
```

Anyways both solutions should work.
Hope that helps :-)

Comment: You're welcome :-) Mark the answer as accepted so that it may help others as well..

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery..

```
$('td[class="red"], button[class="btn btn-default btn-success"]').click();
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. Well received and i learnt something!